# discord bot not adding cooldown to command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I made a bot for me and my friends and this is one of its features it mutes and deafens someone in the vc for 5s and adds a cooldown to the command for 1h but it doesnt add the cooldown any help

```
# Check if the message is a command
if message.content.startswith('!spin'):
    # Get the command and arguments from the message
    command, *args = message.content.split()
    command = command[1:]  # remove the leading exclamation mark

    # Check if the command is on cooldown
    if command in cooldowns and cooldowns[command] > message.created_at:
        # The command is on cooldown, so do not execute it
        return

    # Check which command was used
    if command == 'spin':
        # Scan the voice channels in the server
        for channel in message.guild.voice_channels:
            # Get the members in the voice channel
            members = channel.members
            if not members:
                return

            # Pick a random member from the list of members
            lucky_member = random.choice(members)
            # Mute and deafen the lucky member for 5 seconds
            await lucky_member.edit(mute=True, deafen=True)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)  # delay for 5 seconds
            await lucky_member.edit(mute=False, deafen=False)
            await message.channel.send('command is on cooldown for 1h')

        # Put the command on cooldown for 1 hour
        cooldowns[command] = message.created_at + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: I would recommend changing your commandlist, where you store the cooldowns, to a dictionary. Currently you store the values incorrectly. The brackets after a list are its indices and should not be used for keywords. With a dictionary this would be the correct approach: dict["spin"] = 25.

Comment: @Ventior i have a cooldowns dictionary like this "cooldowns = {}" but its on top of the code

Comment: Woops my bad, seems I have misread something!

Comment: nope it just wasn't listed on the code block i provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem:

```
cooldowns[command] = message.created_at + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

needed to be tabbed once so its on the correct spot for the code to work